# How synchronized on activity work, given activity is recreated on orientation change

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have an activity, in the onCreate function I have created a Thread which reads from XML file and populates the Database and also populates member dataStructures.

I have created synchronized methods to carry out DB population and DataStructure population.

1. Since the lock is on activity[synchronized methods], will it cause any issue when activity is recreated because of orientation change or any config change?
2. Is it correct to use synchronized methods here? or should I use synchronized blocks?
3. How do I handle or take care so that DB is not corrupted?
4. How do I ensure only one instance of DataBaseHelper is present even over activity recreations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do what I think you want to do then I suggest to do the following:

1. Create a thread(HandlerThread named DbAsyncThread or whatever) that handles all the methods for all the db methods.
2. Method should use synchronized blocks. Synchronized methods I use when   there is a public static method. It always depends on what you want to achieve.
3. Incorrect states of db you can handle via exceptions. If there is an exception you throw it or pass it to the ui so that the users or you are notified.
4. Use callbacks. If there is a problem notify via callback about the problem. If there is no context involved there should not be any problem.